# Add in installed and referenced

Tags: excel, add-in, vba

I want to check if addin is installed and is referenced. The below code checks for add in is installed or not. How can i check if its referenced in excel.

By Refernced i mean is Tools > Addins > Addins Dailog box > If addins is installed > check if a addin with particular name is checked.

I would like preferably without any loop.

```
Sub Demo() 
    Dim b As Boolean 
    b = CheckAddin("Solver add-in") 
    MsgBox "Solver is " & IIf(b, "", "not ") & "installed" 
End Sub 

Function CheckAddin(s As String) As Boolean 
    Dim x As Variant 
    On Error Resume Next 
    x = AddIns(s).Installed 
    On Error Goto 0 
    If IsEmpty(x) Then 
        CheckAddin = False 
    Else 
        CheckAddin = True 
    End If 
End Function
```

Comment: "I would like preferably without any loop." Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wbAddin As Workbook

    On Error Resume Next
    Set wbAddin = Workbooks(AddIns("My Addin").Name)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
        'Set wbAddin = Workbooks.Open(AddIns("My Addin").FullName)
        Debug.Print "Not Referenced"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Referenced"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you put here `"My Addin"`?

Comment: Ah I see the reason why... I have updated my post. Try it now.

Answer (score 3):

You need to test is the addin is open, pretty much like any other workbood. This will return True if an addin is loaded:

```
Function AddinIsLoaded(AddinName As String) As Boolean
On Error Resume Next
AddinIsLoaded = Len(Workbooks(AddIns(AddinName).Name).Name) > 0
End Function
```

For example:

```
Sub Test
Debug.Print AddinIsLoaded("Solver add-in")
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 I am very slow today :(

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem that even when the function returns True, I would still get an error when trying to use that addin. It turns out, an addin can be installed, but not "open". So, in addition to checking for the addin, I also check if the addin file is open. If not, I open the addin. See my question and answer here:

[Excel VBA Checking if Addin Is Installed But Not Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413928/excel-vba-checking-if-addin-is-installed-but-not-open/39414003#39414003)