# If exists Add-in then Unistall

Tags: vba, excel, add-in

I want the VBA code which can check if the add-in exists in the list of add-ins

Something like

```
If Application.AddIns("Upload Button") Exists Then
   Application.AddIns("Upload Button").Installed = False
End If
```

Hit me back!

EDIT: I solved this using On Error Resume Next

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.AddIns("Upload Button").Installed = False
On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951518/add-in-installed-and-referenced

Comment: @vardhanam You should add that as an answer and accept it instead of editing your question.  This removes the question from the Unanswered list so others know your problem has been solved.