# VBA: Conditional compilation with implements keyword

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to use compiler conditional constants together with the "implements" keyword, where the interface is in an add-in?

I have the following in a *class module* in my workbook, let's call it book1:

```
#Const Condition1 = 0 ''will be replaced with 1 when add-in is opened
#if Condition1 then
    Implements myAddIn.iInterfaceFoo
#End if
```

I have the add-in myAddIn listed as a reference (i.e. in Tools -> References...).

I'm successfully using the interface with other classes in the add-in, but now I want to call the interface directly in my workbook book1. As long as the add-in is open, when I compile book1 (i.e. Debug -> Compile VBAProject) it compiles successfully.

However, when I try to compile book1 with the add-in closed, I get the error

```
Compile error: User-defined type not defined
```

This is precisely what I'm trying to avoid - otherwise if the add-in is missing (for example on someone else's computer) the spreadsheet itself will still work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have attempted to improve the question. I have instantiated the class, but this is a compiler error not a runtime error. Thanks for the link on `implements` but I'm quite comfortable with how it works :)

Comment: Well, when the `Condition1` is false then your code should not even  attempt to compile the `Implements myAddIn.iInterfaceFoo`. Do you have a problem setting the `Condition1` to true/false depending whether the add-in is loaded or not? Possibly see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15951518/2140173) and [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19726791/2140173)

Comment: That's just it - it does try to compile the `Implements` line, even if `Condition1` is `False`. I'll have a look at those linked answers.

Comment: That's rather a strange behaviour. I haven't been able to reproduce this. For me, when the condition is false, the `Implements` is not compiled.

Comment: Does it still error if you declare the `Condition1` as a conditional compilation argument in the VBProject Properties pane of the add-in workbook?

Comment: Are you implementing an interface on any of Excel's own classes (so on ThisWorkbook, or individual WorkSheets, in particular)? I've had serious trouble caused by doing this - not sure why, but I know my eventual solution was to implement the interface on one of my own classes, and then just store instances of them in Worksheets etc, and all of a sudden the problems went away.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I just had a go at it, and I can NOT get it to enter the conditional when `#Const` is set right before it.  I even tried assigning False values to compiler constants like `VB7` and `Win32` to see if I could override them in case of a naming conflict, and sure enough I can force it to evaluate False when it isn't.

Comment: @MichaelChad, no I didn't, I changed my code in the workbook so that I only ever call the AddIn in a `sub`, not in a `function`, which means that although it might not compile correctly when the AddIn is closed, I don't get errors when trying to open the workbook. If I do manage to figure something out (I've run out of time on this for now), I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking a lot and didn't find a good solution to that problem.

So i wrote the problematic function in another file, and if i need it i activate it like this:

On sp.mdb in a module:

```
Public Function soap30object() As Object
Set soap30object = New SoapClient30
End Function
```

On the main file:

```
Public Sub soap30object()
Dim ob As Object
Dim appAccess As New Access.Application
appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase ("c:\sp\sp.mdb")
Set ob = appAccess.Run("soap30object")
End Sub
```

Have fun!

---

Another solution

Replace the code in Modul on Runtime...

```
     Public Sub replacemodel(mdlname As String, fnd As String, cngto As String)
        Dim toi As Long, oldlin As String, i As Long, firstchr As String, linnewnum As Long, last_ As Boolean
        Dim frm As Form,mdl As Module 
        DoCmd.OpenForm mdlname, acDesign
        Set mdl = Forms(mdlname).Module
        toi = mdl.CountOfLines
        With mdl
            For i = 1 To toi
                linnewnum = i
                oldlin = .lines(i, 1)
                If InStr(oldlin, fnd) <> 0 Then
                    oldlin = Replace(oldlin, fnd, cngto)
                    .ReplaceLine i, oldlin
                    goto nexx
                End If
            Next i
        End With
nexx:
        DoCmd.Close acForm, mdlname, acSaveYes
        Set mdl = Nothing
        'All variables reset when you edit modul on 
        msgbox "Program will restart now..."
        DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll
    end Sub
```