# Excel VBA Checking if Addin Is Installed But Not Open

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to check if a required addin is installed/available before calling scripts within that Addin from the current context:

```
Function IsAddinEnabled(addinName as string) As Boolean
    IsAddinEnabled = True
    Dim myAddin As addin
    On Error GoTo NotExists
    Set myAddin = Application.AddIns2(addinName)
    If myAddin.IsOpen = False Then ' this logic is my workaround
        myAddin.Installed = False 'uninstall 
        myAddin.Installed = True ' install to "Open" the addin
    Else
        myAddin.Installed = True 'redundant
    End If
    Exit Function
NotExists:
    IsAddinEnabled = False
End Function
```

The problem arises when:

`myAddin.IsOpen = false` I had to add this logic to reinstall the addin. It's a slight nuisance/slow down to uninstall and reinstall the addin. Is there a way to force and Addin to "open" without re-installing the addin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @Charles Williams

This is the method I've used:

```
Function IsAddinEnabled(addinName as string) As Boolean
    IsAddinEnabled = True
    Dim myAddin As addin
    On Error GoTo NotExists
    Set myAddin = Application.AddIns2(addinName)
    If myAddin.IsOpen = False Then ' this logic is my workaround
        Workbooks.Open myAddin.Path & "\" & myAddin.Name 'open the addin, if it's not open
    Else
        myAddin.Installed = True 'redundant
    End If
    Exit Function
NotExists:
    IsAddinEnabled = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler way is to check if the addin exists in the workbooks collection.

If it does not you can open it as though it was a workbook assuming you know the path.

(don't need to bother with the addins collection)

Comment: I could use both methods and then use  `workbooks.open myAddin.Path`