# Excel Add-In - Alternative to ActiveMenuBar.Reset

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins, essbase

**Problem:** After an upgrade from Office 2010 to 2013, the Essbase Excel Add-in ("essexcln.xll", which Oracle ended support for in 2013) causes the focus to always return to a window with an active connection, when there is more than 1 window open. If the Essbase Add-In is loaded at startup, Excel also freezes. Note that Smartview has replaced this Add-In but for other reasons I need to continue using it. I can manually go to File > Options > Add-ins > Manage Excel Add-Ins and manually check/un-check when Essbase is causing these errors, but I'd rather do that with a quick keyboard shortcut.

**Workaround:** Create a custom add-in to quickly toggle the Essbase Add-In `installed` property to load and unload it. Maybe an add-in is overkill - but I don't really use a PERSONAL.XLSB, and I'd like this functionality to be available at all times.

**Problem 2:** When the Essbase add-in is unloaded, the "Add-in" Menu bar still shows a custom command: "About Oracle Essbase Spreadsheet Add-in." "Essexcln.xll" is notoriously buggy, and this "About Oracle Essbase Spreadsheet Add-in" can linger on even when the add-in is unchecked manually. My solution is to use `ActiveMenuBar.Reset` - only after I've unloaded the add-in. I don't want to reset if I've just toggled `Installed` to `True`.

Is there an alternative to `ActiveMenuBar.Reset`? This feels like a hack - kind of like using `ActiveCell` or `ActiveSheet` - but I don't want to manually check/un-check the Addin, which may or may not clear the "About Essbase..." anyway.

**Notes:** Yes, maybe it's not the most efficient to loop through `Add-ins`, but there's so few of them that I don't really care. I'd much rather avoid using `ActiveMenuBar`.

[image: ADD-INS Menu bar]

```
Sub Toggle_Essbase_AddIn()

Dim x As AddIn
Dim installed As Boolean

For Each x In Application.AddIns
    If x.Name = "essexcln.xll" Then
        ' Get initial installed status
        installed = x.installed
        ' Toggle
        x.installed = Not x.installed
        ' Reset menu bar if Essbase was initially installed
        If installed Then
            ActiveMenuBar.Reset
        End If

        Exit Sub
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your code is incredibly inefficient, to the point that it's tough to explain why.  Looking at the core of your procedure (after removing wasted space) we have:

```
Sub Toggle_Essbase_AddIn()
    Dim x As AddIn, installed As Boolean
    If x.Name = "essexcln.xll" Then
        installed = x.installed
        x.installed = Not x.installed
        If installed Then
            ActiveMenuBar.Reset
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

First off, this line does absolutely nothing:

```
x.installed = Not x.installed
```

...since it's ***after*** the value of `installed` has been set.

I can only assume that your intention was to toggle the value that's being passed to variable `installed`?

It will save you a lot of confusion if you **get a little more creative with your variable names**, instead of risking a word that, for all intensive purposes, could be considered ***Reserved***.  Without picking apart semantics, it is best not to name your variables with **words that VBA wants to use for other things**, and this is a perfect example why.  Even if VBA doesn't get confused, **you might**, and you have an almost infinite number of other, more meaningful names to pick from.

Assuming that the intention was to toggle the value that's being passed to variable `installed` then you could have gone:

```
If x.Name = "essexcln.xll" Then
    installed = not x.installed
    If installed Then
        ActiveMenuBar.Reset
    End If
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Preferably you should use `Exit` commands sparingly, or not at all -- only when there isn't an option to leave the loop/sub/if "naturally" but I'm not going into that now since it's irrelevant in a moment.

...or better yet:

```
installed = Not ( x.Name = "essexcln.xll" )
If installed Then
    ActiveMenuBar.Reset
End If
```

...or even shorter:

```
If Not ( x.Name = "essexcln.xll" ) then ActiveMenuBar.Reset
```

...so now your whole sub would be:

```
Sub Toggle_Essbase_AddIn()

    Dim x As AddIn
    Dim installed As Boolean

    For Each x In Application.AddIns
        If Not ( x.Name = "essexcln.xll" ) then ActiveMenuBar.Reset
    Next x

End Sub
```

...but you're still being unnecessarily inefficient.

There is no reason to loop through the AddIns.  A quick Google of [`Application.Addins`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-addins-property-excel) shows that it's easiest to refer to the Add-In by it's name.

I've never used Essex, but another quick Google to find the [add-in documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17236_01/epm.1112/esb_ss_user/frameset.htm?toolbar_activate.html) tells me that the name of the add-in is "Oracle Essex".

> Therefore, **one line** replaces your **entire procedure**:
>
> ```
> If Not AddIns("Oracle Essbase").Installed Then ActiveMenuBar.Reset
> ```

(or I'm not sure if it was intended to NOT be `NOT` because your code was unclear) - but this is far more efficient and does the equivalent of your code - as long as you're sure the add-in actually *exists* (not the same as installed, Google it), then this does the same thing as your entire procedure.

If you're not sure if the add-in exists, then Google saves the day again with a link to a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951518/add-in-installed-and-referenced).

Since I don't have the add-in and you haven't included any specific example of the problem, I can't say for sure if this answers the question completely, but I assure you that taking some extra time on one's own due diligence in coding will safe a lot of effort for you - and others - in the end.

Heads up, I had a lot to write here to get to "one line" so I can't guarantee there were no oversights, but the lesson here is more about research-before-coding.

I suggest you study the **documentation** about add-ins and toolbars at **MSDN** as well as documentation specific to the 3rd party add-in at **Oracle** (via the links above, **and** sub-links from those pages) and I am confident that with some effort your solution will become clear.

If not, I suggest you add more information to your question. ...and please, don't attempt to write any "add-ins for add-ins"!

Good Luck (and welcome to Stack Overflow!)

---

...and after all that, I notice that you added a link to an image instead of adding an image, so it would have been more noticeable. I can't tell without clicking the toolbar but I'm pretty sure that's ***not*** a menu bar command.  That's a ribbon group, and it's empty.

Comment: 1)  "First off, this line does absolutely nothing: " - that's not my problem, and works fine. That's the equivalent of checking/un-checking the Add-In "Manage Excel Add-ins". 2) The quick solutions from your proposed Google search - which get more at my question - hint at using "Manage Excel Add-ins" - exactly what I wanted to avoid  in the first place. 3) FWIW, I don't care that much about the question, asked it more out of curiosity, since it currently works. Please do not assume that I have not done my research and/or demean an honest attempt.

Comment: Also, your Essbase link points to "esstoolb.xls." Here is the correct [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36352_01/epm.1112/esb_ss_user/frameset.htm?loading_ssa.html) referencing "essexcln.xll" - but this is not useful at all to my question.

Comment: @BigBen I had mentioned there would be some oversights; I had already spent too much time on one question.   Just a head's up: Questions *"just out of curiosity"* are [discouraged by many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297059). Nonetheless my response demonstrates one example of simplifying redundant code and is a point in the right direction for other current & future users (the point of [so])   - sorry to hear you found no value it in.  Good luck.